# How to set rate limit for specific queries in php with nginx

Tags: server, php, nginx

I have a php file called **"sample.php"**.

This file contains query_string in several different ways. Some innocent users use these query_strings at maybe 100 requests per minute (no problem).

However, some query_strings are used at most 2-3 times a minute and there is no need for more. Bruteforce or ddos requests also come from here.

I can set "sample.php" to 4 requests per minute with the nginx rate limit, but this sometimes causes innocent users to be blocked. I want to be able to set a rate limit for certain query_strings, but I couldn't find a precise way to do this.

**For example:**

*/sample.php?type=stb&action=handshake&token=*

or

*/sample.php?action=handshake&type=stb&token=&mac=**(random_string)***

I want to put rate_limit on such requests but I don't know the way. (I'm not talking about putting rate_limit entirely in sample.php)

Is there someone who can help? Thank you.

Comment: Its enough for me to set rate_limit urls which contain "mac=" or "handshake" strings in url which include sample.php